# How use kafka-topics with SASL auth

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have Kafka brokers in cluster. We use SASL authentication. How can I request for example topics list using `kafka-topics.sh`?

I assume that I should run

```bash
kafka-topics.sh \
--bootstrap-server kafka.broker:9092 \
--command-config config.properties \
--list
```

And to pass values to `config.properties`

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.username=user-name
sasl.password=password


ssl.key.location=/path/to/certs/key.pem
ssl.certificate.location=/path/to/certs/crt.pem
ssl.ca.location=/path/to/certs/ca.pem
```

When I run it I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:553)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:485)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:134)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService$.createAdminClient(TopicCommand.scala:205)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:209)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:50)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.defaultContext(JaasContext.java:131)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.loadClientContext(JaasContext.java:82)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:167)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:524)
```

We use the same values to connect it from `go` service that uses `segmentio` Kafka driver. What config should be?

Comment: you need a configure and store JAAS configuration file, that looks like
```
KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username=(username)
    password=(password);
};
```

Comment: how can I pass certificates there?

Comment: JAAS config doesn't care about certs. It's a credentials setup. Certs stay in config.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass SASL credentials you need to use the [`sasl.jaas.config`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#adminclientconfigs_sasl.jaas.config) setting. `sasl.username` and `sasl.password` are not valid settings with `kafka-topics.sh` (and the Java client).

For example:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
  username="user-name" \
  password="password";
```

Similarly `ssl.key.location`, `ssl.certificate.location` and `ssl.ca.location` are not valid settings, you need to use `ssl.keystore.location` and `ssl.truststore.location` instead. See the full list of configurations: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#adminclientconfigs

See the [SCRAM client configuration section](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_scram_clientconfig) in the Kafka docs if you want more details.

Comment: The error is different now. Does it mean that certificates are wrong?
```
ERR Connection to node -1 () failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
WARN Metadata update failed due to authentication error (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
```

Comment: You need to use the Java settings. I updated the answer

Comment: thanks! If you have a link to explain how to use existing certificates with JKS trust store I will appreciate very much

Comment: If you look at the ssl.* settings in the list, you'll see it's also possible to use PEM certificates. If you use a different format you'll have to find a way to convert them into JKS or PEM

Comment: My apologies for stupid questions, I do all this for the first time. Do you mean, that I can set pem certs in `org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule`?